# В биосе не выставляется приоритет. Хакинтош

Tags: windows, mac, bios

Есть хдд с вин7 и ссд с хакинтошем ( El Capitan ). Сидя на хакитоше - внезапно гаснет монитер и просто выключается комп. (ноутбук asus n56v). Теперь в биосе невозможно поставить приоритет загрузки, нету загрузчика, в котором можно было выбрать загружаемую ось (по моему, стоял кловер). В разделе sata - оба жестких диска видны. Также посредством программ на вин удалось зайти в файловую систему и вытянуть нужные файлы. (MacDrive). Эта программа не показывала ошибки и пишет, что диск исправен.
Я, так понимаю, слетел загрузчик (возможно). Посоветуйте как быть. К слову, хакинтош накатывал не я, жаль будет потерять идеально настроенную систему.
Спасибо

Comment: Не знаю, работает ли этот прием на хакинтошах, но попробуйте держать alt во время включения ПК.

Comment: @ilyaplot к сожалению, такое только на маках